# CompletedProcess is a Generic for mypy

Tags: python, subprocess, mypy

I am using `subprocess.CompletedProcess` as a return type of a function. When running `mypy` with `--strict`, it complains about `Missing type parameters for generic type "CompletedProcess"`. This is a short example for which the problem occurs:

```
import subprocess

def run_command() -> subprocess.CompletedProcess:
    return subprocess.CompletedProcess(args=[], returncode=0, stdout='')
```

I do not understand how `CompletedProcess` is a generic. I checked the reference (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) and can't find any mention.

Randomly adding a generic parameter, for example `-> subprocess.CompletedProcess[str]`, removes the error, but obviously that's not the point. I'd like to be able to hint the return type without defining a generic parameter.

I am using python 3.8.5 and mypy 0.761 and 0.910 (both give the same output).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output (`stdout`/`stderr`) of a subprocess can be either `str` or `bytes`, depending on the arguments. The generic parameter to `CompletedProcess` is *required* to indicate the type of this.

```py
import subprocess

def run_some_command() -> 'subprocess.CompletedProcess[str]':
    """Run some subprocess that captures output as ``str``"""
    return subprocess.CompletedProcess(args=[], returncode=0, stdout='')

def run_other_command() -> 'subprocess.CompletedProcess[bytes]':
    """Run some subprocess that captures output as ``bytes``"""
    return subprocess.CompletedProcess(args=[], returncode=0, stdout=b'')

reveal_type(run_some_command().stdout)  # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.str*'
```

Since only the type hint but not the runtime `subprocess.CompletedProcess` type is generic, it must be quoted.

---

The type declarations for the standard library are part of `typeshed`. In specific, [`CompletedProcess` is currently defined as follows](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/73b4c21ccec6a68788a04c6745b38b53cd306a5d/stdlib/subprocess.pyi#L40-L51):

```py
class CompletedProcess(Generic[_T]):
    # morally: _CMD
    args: Any
    returncode: int
    # These are really both Optional, but requiring checks would be tedious
    # and writing all the overloads would be horrific.
    stdout: _T
    stderr: _T
    def __init__(self, args: _CMD, returncode: int, stdout: Optional[_T] = ..., stderr: Optional[_T] = ...) -> None: ...
    def check_returncode(self) -> None: ...
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
        def __class_getitem__(cls, item: Any) -> GenericAlias: ...
```

Comment: Ah, okay. In my actual code, I am not creating the `CompletedProcess` myself but I return the result of `subprocess.run()`. When looking at the definition of `CompletedProcess`, it says: "By default, all communication is in bytes [...]. If in text mode [...] stdout and stderr will be strings [...] Text mode is triggered by setting [...] encoding [...]." I am setting encoding to "utf-8" in my actual `run()` call. Am I therefore right when I assume that my actual return type is `CompletedProcess[str]`?

Comment: I just tried it out. Using `r = subprocess.run(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` ->  `type(r.stdout)` is `<class 'bytes'>`. Using `r = subprocess.run(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')` ->  `type(r.stdout)` is `<class 'str'>`. Thanks! :)

Comment: At runtime, I ran into another problem, as `CompletedProcess` is not generic at runtime, causing this error: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. This will apparently be solved in the future (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runtime_troubles.html#runtime-troubles) but for now, I made the type hint a string literal `'subprocess.CompletedProcess[str]'`.

Comment: @Bert Thanks for the comment, missed that one. Update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Bert If you are using Python 3.7+, you can also use `from __future__ import annotations` to solve the issue of `CompletedProcess` not being generic at runtime. It being generic was not added until 3.9, so for 3.7-3.8 you can use the `__future__` import above.

Comment: @phoenix Thanks, I had that planned already in another case, good to know it also applies here. Unfortunately, for the time being my main systems are stuck on Ubuntu 18.04 (python 3.6).

Comment: Thanks @phoenix, that was the solution for me. I would upvote your answer.